# Finding expected present value in vba

Tags: excel, vba

data is as follows(only a subsetof original data):
Age   qx
17    .006
18    .0085
19     .0047
20...   .998

I want t find summation(k ranging from 0 to infifnity) (v^(k+1))*kpx*q(x+k)
where x is the age which the user shall enter as input into the function
v is 1/(1+ interest rate)
qx is one year mortality rate
px is 1- qx
kpx is product of px[age:age+k-1]
interest rate will be entered as input by the user in a function
k is any no. between 0 to 120

I want to make a function for finding out present value of whole life assurance.
For that I need to find kpx

```
Dim qx as long
Qx= range("A1:A5").value

Dim px as long
Px=1-qx

Dim kpx as long
Kpx=product(px(age:age+k-1))
```

Comment: `Qx= range("A1:A5").value` won't work because the `.Value` of a multi-cell range is a 2D Variant array.

Comment: Sharing some sample data with inputs and expected outputs would help here. It's not clear what you actually want to do here so hard to give you any advise